# How to chant Shatru samhara mantra dedicated to God Murugan?

Tags: mantras, kartikeya

Shatru samhara mantra will help to develop good personality via destroying bad thing on mind ?

and How to chant the mantra ?

Comment: Is it in Tamil? - https://youtu.be/N6CZTyhvUAc

Comment: What do you mean by chanting? Are you looking for rules which have to be followed while chanting? Or pronunciation?